# <<- meaning in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What does `<<-` mean in the following method/context?

```
class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
def destroy_associations
  association(:#{middle_reflection.name}).delete_all(:delete_all)
  association(:#{name}).reset
  super
end
RUBY
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It describes the beginning of a here document. Probably what you are confused is that the here document starts from the next line; everything that follows that expression within that line is a continuation to the here document. Thus, given that the content of here document is represented as `heredoc`, the expression is equivalent to:

```
class_eval heredoc, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
```

which means to evaluate the content of the here document in a class environment, and whenever an error is raised, associate the location with the current file (`__FILE__`) and the first line of the here document (i.e. the line after the beginning, `__LINE__ + 1`) should be counted as line 1.

Answer (score 8):

It signals the beginning of a multiline string, also known as "heredoc".

The format can be either:

```
<<[ID]
contents
[ID]
```

or

```
<<-[ID]
contents
[ID]
```

The difference being that in the first case, the closing [ID] must be located at the beginning of the line, while in the second case, the [ID] can be indented to have cleaner code.

Comment: It's probably worth it to mention you can use any letters or numbers for a heredoc: `puts <<-_END_`;`stuff`;`_END_` also you can do string interpolation in heredocs by doing the whole curly bracket thing: `x = "string"`;`puts <<- -END-`;`#{x}`;`-END-`

Answer (score 5):

It's a "heredoc", or multiline string. The `<<-RUBY` is the start and the `RUBY` by itself is the end.

http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html